# Broadcast string with torch.distributed and NCCL backend

Tags: python, pytorch, distributed

What is the robust way to broadcast a string using `torch.distributed` with `nccl` backend?

```
import torch.distributed as dist

foo = "info"
dist.broadcast(foo, 0)
# everybody has the same foo now
```

Answer (score 1):

[There is a function for that in PT](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/distributed.html#torch.distributed.broadcast_object_list) already that will broadcast a list of picklable (and not only) objects without the need to manually covert objects to binary and move them to GPU:

```
import torch.distributed as dist

# init PG or something here
# ...

foostring = "broadcast_this"
dist.broadcast_object_list([foostring], 0)
```